# Using continue in python ternary?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, continue, ternary

How can I use continue in python ternary? Is that even possible?

E.g.

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     x = i if i == 5 else continue
```

give a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

If continue in ternary is possible, is there any other way of doing this:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     if i ==5:
...             x = i #actually i need to run a function given some condition(s)
...     else:
...             continue
... 
>>> x
5
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot; `continue` is a statement and the conditional expression is an expression, and you cannot use a statement inside an expression. After all, the `continue` statement doesn't produce a value for the conditional expression to return.

Use an `if` *statement* instead:

```
if i == 5:
    x = i
else:
    continue
```

or better:

```
if i != 5:
    continue
x = i
```